springboot RestController call xxx.json 404 error
i use springboot to api server..
controller
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/health")
public class HealthController {

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HealthController.class);

    @GetMapping("")
    public boolean health() {
        return true;
    }

    @GetMapping("/message")
    public String message() {
        return "message";
    }
}

WebMvcConfigurer
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
    public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
        MediaType jsonMediaType = MediaType.valueOf("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
        configurer
                .mediaType("json", jsonMediaType)
                .mediaType("html", MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
                .mediaType("zip", MediaType.valueOf("application/zip"))
                .mediaType("txt", MediaType.valueOf("text/html;charset=UTF-8"))
                .defaultContentType(jsonMediaType)
                .ignoreAcceptHeader(true)
                .useRegisteredExtensionsOnly(true);
    }
}

/health -> 200 OK
/health.json -> 404 ERROR
It's a minor problem, but I want to solve it.
call url with .json extension, result 200 OK

As you are using Spring Boot for starters remove @EnableWebMvc as that disables large parts of the Spring Boot auto-configuration.
